# Динамическая диспетчеризация вызовов методов

Tags: java, объекты, наследование

К примеру у нас есть класс Film, который содержит в себе информацию об одном фильм(длительсность, список актеров, жанры и т.д.). Класс FilmList который содержит в себе массив

```
Film[] array = new Film[0];
```

Этот класс имеет в себе много методов, позволяющих обрабатывать этот список(добавлять фильм в список, удалять из списка и т.д.). И есть два класса: FilmOnComputer и FilmOnDvd. Оба этих класса наследуются от класса Film. Вопрос в том, какая разница каким образом созданный объект добавлять в массив:

```
Film film1 = new FilmOnDvd("The Matrix");
```

Или же

```
FilmOnDvd film2 = new FilmOnDvd("The Matrix");
```

Будет ли в последствии какая-то разница при работе с объектами созданными каким-либо из этих двух способов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тип ссылки влияет лишь на интерфейс, поведение же определяется типом объекта.

Так что нет, в данном случае разницы не будет.